# Adding variables to a class

Tags: python

Given a class `Mitarbeiter` with the constructor `__init__` which is creating 3 variables. Can additional variables be added by another method in python? Example below:

```
class Mitarbeiter:
    species = "Homo sapiens"
    
    #Klassenmethoden ändern nur Klassenattribute
    #statische Methoden verwenden werder Instanz- noch Klassenattribute
    #konstruktor

    
    def __init__ (self, vorname, name, personalnummer):
        self.__vorname = vorname
        self.__name = name
        self.__personalnummer = personalnummer

    def _def_abteilung(self, abteilung):
        self.__abteilung = abteilung
    
    def _set_vorgesetzter (self, vorgesetzter):
        self.__vorgesetzer = vorgesetzter

    @property
    def get_abteilung(self,):
        return self.__abteilung
```

when I create an Object of `Mitarbeiter` with the variables `vorname`, `name` and `personalnummer` I can call later the method `_def_abteilung` to set some more information to the Object `Mitarbeiter`.

```
ma1 = Mitarbeiter("Franz", "Bauer", 736) #--> Works
ma1._def_abteilung("Test") #--> Works
ma1.abteilung #--> does not work, any Ideas?
```

Comment: By Python convention, methods and variables beginning with an underscore aren't meant to be accessed from outside the class (i.e. using an instance). Also you never defined a variable or method named `abteilung` (without any underscores).

Comment: The "`_name` is private" convention is a _convention_, but "`__name`" mangles the name so `ma1.__abteilung` literally doesn't exist. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-name-mangling-and-how-to-use-underscores-e67b529f744f

Comment: don't ever write getters and setters like that, use @property. and fix the naming of your methods, no need to add `_def_`, `_set_`  (or `_get` for properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The "`_name` is private" convention is a *convention* (privacy isn't *enforced* in any way),
- "`__name`" mangles the name so `ma1.__abteilung` literally doesn't exist outside the class.
- See [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name) and [Python Name Mangling and How to Use Underscores](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-name-mangling-and-how-to-use-underscores-e67b529f744f)

You can set attributes for an object anywhere -- if you changed `self.__abteilung` to `self.abteilung`, that name wouldn't be mangled by the interpreter and you would see the `abteilung` attribute defined on all `Mitarbeiter` objects.

Consider the following `TestClass` example:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def set_b(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def set_mangled(self, m):
        self.__m = m
        print("Mangled", self.__m)

    def get_mangled(self):
        return self.__m
```

- The `a` attribute is set in the `__init__`, so `t.a` always exists

```
t = TestClass(0)
print(t.a) # 0
print(t.b) # AttributeError
```

- The `b` attribute is only set in the `set_b` method, so it only exists on an object after that method is called. The method can set an attribute of the object using the reference `self`. Trying to print `t.b` before setting it throws an `AttributeError`

```
t.set_b(10)
print(t.a) # 0
print(t.b) # 10
print(t.c) # AttributeError
```

- The `c` attribute is set only once you run the line `t.c = 100`. As you can see, it is possible to set the attribute from *outside* the class. Trying to access `t.c` before setting it throws an AttributeError.

```
t.c = 100
print(t.a) # 0
print(t.b) # 10
print(t.c) # 100
```

- The `__m` attribute is defined as a mangled name. Inside the class, it is accessed using `self.__m`. Outside the class, the name is mangled to `_TestClass__m`, so it is not accessible as `t.__m` or `t.m`.

```
t.set_mangled(1000) # Mangled: 1000
print(t.get_mangled()) # 1000
print(t._TestClass__m) # 1000
print(t.__m) # AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute '__m'
print(t.m) # AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'm'
```